# CSS: position text inside an h2

Tags: css

I have a background image in my h2, is there a way to position the text inside of the h2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use padding and alignment to place the text. Example:

```
h2 {
  font-size:15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 30px 20px 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the h2 within a span or div, put the image in there and then use padding to position the h2 within that.  An h2 is text.

Comment: Yes, but if you apply a background image to the `h2`, you can then add visual appeal without any extra HTML markup.

Comment: Well, that's right, but I would still think it is more manageable in the long run to keep things separate.  One can then just add the padding and margins (or if you want to be strange, borders).

Comment: Probably not. Avoiding the extra elements will clean up both your HTML and your CSS, since you don't have to manage two separate styles for a single UI element.

Answer (score 0):

1. padding
2. text-indent
3. line-height
4. wrap the text inside with a div/span and margin/padding/text/indent
5. wrap text inside and position:relative on h2, position absolute on inner text element.

and more.. 
Take your pick.

Comment: ^ line-height is another spanner in your toolbox on top of meder's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

use css padding:

```
{
    padding-left:8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 style='display:block; width:100%; height:40px; text-align:center'>text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding padding and a constant width / height to position:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  h2
  {
    background: #DEF;
    width: 400px; height: 100px
    padding: 40px 40px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Sample</h2>
</body>
</html>
```